# AngularJS Dependency Injector

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I've been using angularJS for a while now, and I was wondering if it is correct to use the DI this way. Let's say I want to define a service, which needs some angular services. I would probably write the following:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.service('myService', function($q, $http) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Is it correct if I write this instead:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.service('myService', function($injector) {
    // DI
    var $q = $injector.get('$q');
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
});
```

I find it clearer and easier to add / remove dependencies.

Thanks for the heads up :-)

Comment: As it stands, minification will break because `$injector` will be renamed.  in either case, you should use a name (string) for dependencies.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to mention I have gulp-ngmin which is rewriting it right for me. If you ommit the minification part, is it correct ? I'll edit my post cause it's not really about minification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct in both ways, for me i prefer to use the first example, because you can inject the dependencies more fast, and in a similar way as you 'inject' modules between your same modules.